# Work Manager problem with Periodic Work Request and Location Updates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi

Work Manager version : 1.0.0-alpha08 i tested it for many days it worked fine. But now its not working properly. Actually I was fetching device location at interval of 15 minutes and sending it to the server. So I used Periodic Work Request for that. And later I made another sample just to check but again its not working sometime it runs at given time interval and most of the time it is not doing its task at that interval. Please suggest is it any issue in Work Manager library or any problem from my end ?

[Here is the my worker class which get location and send it to server periodically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p7Ta.png)

[And here I started the task by enqueuing it in WorkManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQpGO.png)

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593800/1318946